# Function to set terminal window title and perform SSH login

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, gnome-terminal

I am often logging to different devices in the local network via SSH. All the devices have the IP address 10.0.0.XYZ. I would like to log by simple command `dev XYZ` and rename the terminal to `DEVICE 10.0.0.XYZ` by the same command. I have written a few bash functions:

```
function login_dev(){
    sshpass -p 'password' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@10.0.0.$*
}

function set-title() {
  if [[ -z "$ORIG" ]]; then
    ORIG=$PS1
  fi
  TITLE="\[\e]2;$*\a\]"
  export PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}
  echo "Title set to ${PS1}"
}


function dev() {
  if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]
  then
      echo "I need to know the IP"
  else
    title="Device 10.0.0.$*"
    set-title ${title} &
    login_dev $*
  fi
}
```

However, the title of the terminal window changes after the SSH session is terminated, which is pretty useless. Any way to force the change to show BEFORE the session starts?

Comment: You are changing the wrong prompt you need to set the prompt on the remote side.

Comment: If I remove the `&` there is no change in functionality. It was just an attempt to make it work the way I want

Well... the prompt on the remote side is empty. When I call `the set-title` on it's own by hand, and then call the `dev()`, I get what I want, just not the in way I want to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks for your update. The terminal title is set by characters sent to it, including the remote machine you are connecting to. Some possible solutions can be found at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40830/54675 and https://superuser.com/a/1379284/84807. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78492/54675.